# (Proof Check) Orientability of zero set of smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-verification

Could you check my proof that zero set of a smooth function on Euclidean space is an orientable manifold?

Suppose $g:R^{n-k}\times R^k\to R^k$ is smooth such that $\text{rank}g'(x)=k$ whenver $g(x)=g(x_1,x_2)=0$ then I'll show that $M=g^{-1}(0)$ is orientable. By the constant rank theorem, for each $x \in R^{n-k}\times R^k$ there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ and a smooth differeomorphism $h:U_x \to R^n$ such that $g \circ h(u,v)=v$ and $h(0)=x$. Let $P:R^{n-k}\times R^k$ be orthonormal projection onto $R^k$, then $G_x=P\circ h^{-1}$ defined on $h(R^n)$ is smooth, and $DG_x(p)=P\circ Dh^{-1}(p)$ so restriction of $DG_x(p)$ on $0\times R^k$ is 1-1, so that implicit function theorem can be applied.
We see that there exists an open set $V_{x_1}$ and $V_{x_2}$,containing $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively, and a differentiable function $\phi_x^*:V_{x_1}\to R^k$ such that $G_x(u,\phi_x^*(u))=0$. Put $V_x=V_{x_1}$. This induces a differentiable function $\phi_x:V_x\to R^n$ defined by $\phi_x(u)=(u,\phi_x^*(u)$.

First, $\phi_x$ is injective and $\phi_x^{-1}(u,v)=u$ on its domain. So $\phi_x^{-1}$ is continuous.

I will show that each $\phi_x$ is a coordinate patch and that $\det (\phi_y^{-1} \circ \phi_x)'>0$. Let $V_x\cap V_y\neq \varnothing$ then if $\phi_y^{-1} \circ \phi_x(u)=p$, $(u,\phi_x^*(u))=(p,\phi_x^*(p))$ which is true if and only if $u=p$. So we see that $\phi_y^{-1} \circ \phi_x(u)$ is identity on $V_x\cap V_y$ so that $\det (\phi_y^{-1} \circ \phi_x)'=1>0$.

Put $A=D\phi_x(u)$ then I'll show that $\text{rank }A=k$ for $u\in V_x$. Matrix representation of $A$ is:
[\begin{bmatrix} I\\ \frac{\partial \phi_x^*}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix}]
where $I$ is a $n-k \times n-k$ identity matrix. So we see that $A_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ for $1\leq i \leq n-k$, $1\leq j\leq n-k$. So the entries $(A^T A)_{ij}$ of $n-k \times n-k$ matrix satisfies
[(A^T A)_{ij}=\sum *{l=1}^{n-k} A*{il}A_{jl}=\delta_{ij}]
so that $A^T A=I$. Since the sum of rank of $A$ and null rank of $A$ is equal to $n-k$ and $A$ cannot have any null space, we see that rank of $A$ is equal to $n-k$.

Furthermore, since $G_x\circ \phi_x=0$, we see that $h^{-1} \circ \phi_x \subset R^{n-k}(V_x)\times {0}$ so that $g \circ \phi_x=g\circ h(h^{-1} \circ \phi_x)=0$. This tells us that $\phi_x:V_x \to W_x \cap M$ for some open set $W_x$ in $R^n$.

Since $\phi_x$ satisfies all the conditions of coordinate functions and $\det (\phi_y^{-1} \circ \phi_x)'=1>0$, $M$ is orientable.